# What kind of technology allows you to send digital signals over 100 meters?

Tags: wireless-networking, bluetooth

I'm looking for a way to send digital signals over ~100 meters. I have researched into technologies such as NFC and bluetooth but their range seems to be limited. I used to own this toy called [Eye Link Communicators](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00008RUQJ) which would allow me to carry out the types of communications that I am looking for. I would be either satisfied by knowing what Eye Link Communicators uses in the inside or another technology that does something similar.

Comment: What is your application? If you can’t tell, how many hosts do you want to connect? Do they come and go Are they fixed or moving around fixed or moving targets? Are there obstacles in between? Do you need two-way communication or will one way be enough? What bandwidth do you need? What delay? Without details, “send large digits in base 13 through snail mail” would be a valid answer.

Comment: We want to have a two-way communication between moving targets (but at walking speeds maximum) where there possibly would be obstacles in between. We don't need much bandwidth (like simple 100 character messages) and a few second of delay wouldn't hurt I suppose.

Comment: If this is an IoT application you're talking about, [802.11ah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11ah) was created for just that purpose.

Answer (score 4):

[IEEE 802.11ah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11ah) (Wi-Fi HaLow) is precisely the sort of protocol you'd want to use for this application. It's a low-power, low-data rate variant of Wi-Fi which uses 900 MHz spectrum for long-range communication, especially for IoT devices.

Answer (score 1):

You can use XBee modules if you don't want to make your own module. They support different wired interfaces and distances much longer than 100 meters.